# CSS checkbox+ label under image with ul/li

Tags: html, css

Having the following code.

```
<div id="table">
    <li>
        <img id="img_friend_1" src="">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="form_friend_1" name="form[friend][]" />
        <label for="form_friend_1" >My name</label>
    </li>
</div>
```

My CSS

```css
#table{
    display:  table;
    width:auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
input {
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
}
```

Right now I got this. Next to the picture is the text.

[image] [//checkbox] My name

I want to place the checkbox with the label under the picture. The picture should be in the middle of checkbox and the label.

[image]

[//checkbox] My name

Actually CSS is pretty easy and I don't have actually problems with CSS, but I am stucked. I searched by stackoverflow and tried a lot of css combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your input and label in another `div`:

```
<li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="form_friend_1" name="form[friend][]" />
        <label for="form_friend_1" >My name</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mRk3S/

Comment: But then the image is not centered above the checkbox and label.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your input and label and then align into center like this

Html

```
<div id="table">

    <li>
        <img id="img_friend_1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsxB5.gif" style="width:150px">
        <div class="wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="form_friend_1" name="form[friend][]" />
        <label for="form_friend_1" >My name</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Here is your `.wrap` class

```
.wrap
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: have your label aligned with checkbox..?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I ended up here but you don't need to use wrappers to achieve this effect.

adding `display:block` to your li img will cause a line-break for anything that follows. `position:relative; margin:0 auto;` centers your image.

Adding `text-align:center` to your li will center the text.

This jsfiddle has the effect I assumed you were trying to achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/wxooa3tq/2/

I also assume you sorted this issue however any future readers may find this helpful